# how to control the color of a region outside inset axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to control the color around a region between the inset axis and a certain border around it,e.g. between the blue border and the inset axis

[image]

this can be easily done for a normal axis but I can't figure out how to do it for an inset axis, what I do is like [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-plot-background-color-in-matplotlib/), same as this example but for an inset axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12857), the inset axes do not have a background that can be changed (they're just an `Axes` object). What is recommended there is to create a patch the size of the axes using `ax.get_tightbbox` and place it behind the inset axes.

Update: Inspired by @[Redox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16404872/redox)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76868519/12131013) posted shortly after mine, I've added a border variable to my example and the forgotten `zorder` so that the plot lines are behind the patch.

Here is a short example of how that can be done.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[5.5, 2.8])
axins = ax.inset_axes([0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5])

x = [0, 2]
y = [0, 2]

ax.plot(x, y)
axins.plot(x, y)

coords = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(axins.get_tightbbox())
border = 0.02
w, h = coords[1] - coords[0] + 2*border
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(coords[0]-border, w, h, fc="green", 
                           transform=ax.transAxes, zorder=2))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The inset axis itself doesn't have a figure. So, to give a color, you will need to add a rectangle patch and set it to the color you want. Below is a simple illustration of the same. Have added a variable buffer that indicates how big (thick) you need the patch to be. The rest is basically drawing an addition box. Hope this helps.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10), c='g')
axin1 = ax.inset_axes([0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3])
axin1.plot(range(5),c='r')
buffer=0.1
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((
    0.5-buffer, 0.4-buffer), 
    0.3+2*buffer, 0.3+2*buffer, 
    linestyle="-", edgecolor="k", facecolor="b", 
    linewidth=1, zorder=5,
    transform=ax.transAxes))
```

[image]